# How does Laravel scope chaining call scopes from the base class not the Builer?

Tags: laravel, scope

Let there is a model named `User` with two scopes `ScopeF1()` and `ScopeF2()`. We can write

```
User::f1()->f2()->get();
```

and it performs the scopes and returns the result. From what I know, the scopes return an instance of `Builder` because we for example call `query->where(...,...)` inside it. When in code

```
User::f1()->f2()->get();
```

It calls `f1()`, an instance of `Builder` is returned and based of chaining rule, it must call `f2()` from `Builder` but in Laravel,  it calls `f2()`of class `User` not `Builder` and I don't know the logic behind it. I would be appreciated if anyone can explain how it works.

## Update

What I am trying to do is to implement a default scope for every field of a model in my project. For example, if model User contains `mobile` field, then I can use the following scope without actually writing its function

```
User::mobileScope($value)->...
```

To do so every model extends an abstract class `EntityAbstract` which in turn extends `Model` class. Every model in my project contains a static function `mappedFields()` which returns a key-value array of camel case-actual field names. for example

```
return [
   'firstName' => 'first_name',
   'lastName' => 'last_name',
   'mobile' => 'mobile' 
 ];
```

A function `fn($value)` also exists which returns field name of a given camel case value. As an example `User::fn('firstName')` returns `first_name`.

In `EntityAbstract` I have the following functions

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    if (str_ends_with($name, "Scope")) {
        $scopeField = substr($name, 0, -5);
        $mappedFields = static::mappedFields();
        if (array_key_exists($scopeField, $mappedFields)) {
            return $this->where(static::fn($scopeField), $arguments[0]);
        } else
            return parent::__call($name, $arguments);
    } else
        return parent::__call($name, $arguments);
}

public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
{
    if (str_ends_with($name, "Scope")) {
        $scopeField = substr($name, 0, -5);
        $mappedFields = static::mappedFields();
        if (array_key_exists($scopeField, $mappedFields)) {
            $model = new static();
            return $model->where(static::fn($scopeField), $arguments[0]);
        }
        else
            return parent::__callStatic($name, $arguments);
    } else
        return parent::__callStatic($name, $arguments);
}
```

I called `parent::__callStatic($name, $arguments)` in order to make sure the work flow of Laravel is not interrupted  when the conditions of my scope is not satisfied.

Now the problem is when I write

```
User::mobileScope('123456')->first()
```

it works perfectly but when I write

```
User::mobileScope('123456')->nameScope('xyz')->first()
```

it throws the error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::nameScope()

As you see, the `mobileScope` returns as instance of `Builder` not the `User` class and `nameScope()` is undefined in `Builder`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the API for Models, and see if you can backtrace how that is happening: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html. I don't know the exact process either, but Model instances _are_ Builder instances; it's why you can do `Model::first()->where('id', 1)->first()` and get a Model that matches `id: 1`. That syntax is silly; you'd just do `Model::where('id', 1)->first()`, or `Model::find(1)`, but the fact you _can_ do that is important in understanding how they all connect to each other.

Comment: If your f1() is returning a Builder Object, add `return $this;` at the end of the method, so chaining is enabled.

Comment: @ManuelGlez for `f2()`, the `$this` is instance of `Builder` not the model. Actually I'm trying to implement the scopes i pure PHP and I have the mentioned problem

Comment: It would be useful to see your code, so we can catch the idea of what you a trying to achieve. If f1 and f2 ar scoped methods you should be returning a query in both and they would be chainable by default.

Comment: @ManuelGlez I added my codes

Comment: @TimLewis I added my codes

Comment: @MamaD I answered you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are complicating things with those calls and static functions as almost practically you are overriding scopes behaviour of yours models.

It wouldn't be better to declare dynamic scopes as declared in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#dynamic-scopes).

```php
     /**
     * Scope a query to only include users with a given field value.
     *
     * @param Builder $query
     * @param $field
     * @param $value
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function scopeWithField(Builder $query, $field, $value): Builder
    {
        return $query->where($field, $value);
    }
```

Using as

```php
    $user = User::withField('name','Manuel Glez')->withField('email','manuel@mydomain.com')->get();
```

or even you can improve that and pass another param which specify the operator to use and make it default to `'='`

```
    public function scopeWithField(Builder $query, $field, $value,$operator='='): Builder
    {
        return $query->where($field,$operator ,$value);
    }
```

So using as before continues working, but now you can query with operators like
`<,>,>=`

etc...

Hope this help

Comment: Very nice solution. Despite of the fact it doesn't answer my solution how chaining works in scopes, but it certainly solves the problem.

Comment: Actually I didn't break Laravel default behavior on magic function because I called its parent and it works.

Comment: If you inspect https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php from line  1191. You will see that scope method bind $this to $builder object and return a builder object, so this is the standar way in php to chain methods.